# How can you copy a row excluding values where the destination is null?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How can I write an SQL query to copy all column values from row 1, into row 2, excluding columns that are null in row 2?

```
id  oldNum  newNum  status     time
1   205     333    complete     2018-06-05 13:14:37
2   209     444     null        2018-06-05 13:14:37
```

The expected result would be

```
id  oldNum  newNum  status     time
1   205     333    complete     2018-06-05 13:14:37
2   205     333     null        2018-06-05 13:14:37
```

With status remaining null.

Answer (score 0):

an insert select would be what youre looking for

```
insert into your_table
select * from your_table where id=1
where id = 2
```

or to keep that null value

```
INSERT INTO your_table (id,oldNum,newNum,time)
SELECT id,oldNum,NewNum,time FROM your_table where id=1
WHERE id=2;
```

Comment: the one table i am working having more than 50 columns and i want a generic way to copy one  in to other row and dont copy for all not null column in second row

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM table WHERE primarykey = 1;
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET primarykey = NULL;
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

As a temp table, there should never be more than one record, so you don't have to worry about the primary key. Setting it to null allows MySQL to choose the value itself, so there's no risk of creating a duplicate.

If you want to be super-sure you're only getting one row to insert, you could add LIMIT 1 to the end of the INSERT INTO line.

Note that I also appended the primary key value (1 in this case) to my temporary table name.

Comment: i want to keep the second row null column value as it is without coping column value from first row